# Parsing scheme vectors in haskell using arrays

Tags: arrays, haskell, parsec

I'm attempting the Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours tutorial and as someone new to haskell it's pretty difficult.
I'm currently working on a problem where I'm supposed to add the ability to parse scheme vectors (section 3.4 exercise 2).

I'm using this data type:

```
data LispVal = Atom String                  
         | List [LispVal]                   
         | Vector (Array Int LispVal)
```

To parse, I'm looking for '#(' then trying to parse the vector contents, drop them in a list and convert that list to an array.

I'm trying to use a list parsing function that I already have and am using but it parses scheme lists into the LispVal List above and I'm having a hard time getting that back into a regular list. Or at least that's what I think my problem is.

```
lispValtoList :: LispVal -> [LispVal]
lispValtoList (List [a]) = [a]

parseVector :: Parser LispVal
parseVector = do string "#("
             vecArray <- parseVectorInternals       
             char ')'
             return $ Vector vecArray

parseVectorInternals :: Parser (Array Int LispVal)
parseVectorInternals = listToArray . lispValtoList . parseList  

listToArray :: [a] -> Array Int a
listToArray xs = listArray (0,l-1) xs
    where l = length xs
```

and here's the list parser:

```
parseList :: Parser LispVal
parseList = liftM List $ sepBy parseExpr spaces
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks,
Simon

-edit-
Here's the compilation error I get:

> Couldn't match expected type `a ->
>   LispVal'
>          against inferred type`Parser LispVal' In the second argument of
>   `(.)' namely`parseList' In the second
>   argument of `(.)' namely`
>   lispValToList . parseList' In the
>   expression: listToArray .
>   lispValToList . parseList

Comment: Do you get any error message when you compile the code?  I think that the definition of `parseVectorInternals` has a type error, but I am not sure if it is the only error in the code or not.  Also, the indentation of the definition of `parseVector` is weird.

Comment: I edited the original question to include the error - the parseVector indenting is a rendering issue, it's fine in the actual code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not provide `lispValtoList` but I suppose that it have the following type

```
lispValtoList :: LispVal -> [LispVal]
```

This would suggest the compiler to think that `parseList` is of type `a -> LispVal`. But it is not since it is `Parser LispVal` and so something like `P String -> [(LispVal,String)]`.

You have to extract the `LispVal` value that was parsed before putting it in a list. 
So `parseVectorInternals` must probably look like

```
parseVectorInternals = do parsedList <- parseList 
                          let listOfLispVal = lispValtoList parsedList
                          return $ listToArray listOfLispVal
```

You could write something more compact, but this code tries to be self-documented ;)

Comment: Fraikin - Whoops, it's there now. I guess what I was trying to do is exactly what you're saying I should do. The intent of lispValToList is to get the haskell list out of the `LispVal List`. Are you saying that I'm using the (.) operator incorrectly?

Comment: @SimonBolivar In this case, the (.) operator is incorrect because the return value of `parseList` doesn't match the argument of `lispValToList`.  `parseList` returns a monad, which is sort of like a box holding a value.  The `<-` inside a `do` block takes the value out of the box, then you can pass the value to `lispValToList`.  (http://learnyouahaskell.com/ has a better explanation of monads)

Comment: @SimonBolivar Exactly... the problem comes from the composition operator. You need to lift `lispValtoList` to compose him (look at `Control.Monad` if you don't know what lifting is). It seems that John F. Miller gives possibles corrections.

Comment: @Alex and @Benoit Thanks, I didn't understand that the `<-` was lifting. That helps clear some things up. 
I just had a really long comment about how the code still didn't work though until I realized that I need to use return to get the `Array` back into the `Parser` monad. It appears to work now.

Answer (score 2):

`parseList` is a Monad of type `parser LispVal` whereas lispValtoList wants a plain LispVal so:

```
parseVectorInternals = listToArray . lispValtoList `liftM` parseList
```

If you are where I was 8 weeks ago reading the same book the following will help you as well:

All these lines are equivalent:

```
parseVectorInternals = (listToArray . lispValtoList) `liftM` parseList
parseVectorInternals = liftM (listToArray . lispValtoList) parseList
parseVectorInternals = parseList >>= \listLispVal -> return listToArray (lispValtoList listLispVal)
parseVectorInternals = do 
  listLispVal <- parseList 
  return listToArray (lispValtoList listLispVal)
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps although I think that there may be a couple of problems with your solution. First, `parseVectorInternals` is of type `Parser (Array Int LispVal)` so I need a `return` or equivalent (another `liftM`?) to get it back into the correct monad. Second, the first code solution gives the error: _Precedence parsing error cannot mix '.' [infixr 9] and 'liftM' [infixl 9] in the same infix expression_ 
I'm not sure what to do with that one. But, the version with the `do` block works if I preface the last line with `return $`